# C# How to get specific item from nested array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following model:

```
public class Car
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public IList<Driver> Drivers {get; set;}
}

public Driver 
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public bool IsActive {get; set;}
}
```

How can I select driver that is active?

```
var carId = "...";
var activeDriver = await _carCollection.Find(a => a.Id == carId
            && a.Drivers.Any(e=>e.IsActive))
            .Project(a=>a.Drivers)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

This code returns `IList<Driver>`, so all items. But I want to retrieve only one `Driver` that is active.

Comment: Unwind the drivers, select only the active ones. Or do the same in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically need to include the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in order to just return the matched array element from the query conditions given. You can do this with `ElementAt(-1)`

```
var activeDriver = await _carCollection.Find(a => a.Id == carId
        && a.Drivers.Any(e => e.IsActive))
        .Project(a => a.Drivers.ElementAt(-1))
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

And can also be written as:

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

var activeDriver = await _carCollection.Find(
         builder.Eq("Id", carId) & builder.Eq("Drivers.IsActive", true))
        .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Drivers.$"))
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

If I run either of those then I get the serialized output of what get's sent to MongoDB as:

```
 { 
    "find" : "cars",
    "filter" : { "_id" : "a", "Drivers" : { "$elemMatch" : { "IsActive" : true } } },
    "projection" : { "Drivers.$" : 1, "_id" : 0 },
    "limit" : 2,
    "$db" : "test"
 }
```

Which matches exactly what the query should be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tred it, but I get error: 
"Command find failed: Positional projection 'Drivers.$' does not match the query document.."

Comment: @user348173 Which form are you trying? Make sure you actually include part of the query to test for the `IsActive` is `true`. So if there is nothing trying to match an element of `Drivers` then you get that error.

Comment: I use the first form. Yes, I forgot to put Any. Anyway, now I get null  result. But, in the database I see that one item has true

Comment: @user348173 It should not matter how many they are as the positional `$` operator only returns the "first". Please do the query the second way for me whilst I check the LINQ syntax. Which is harder to check because I need to basically recreate your class structure.

Comment: @user348173 Included the logged query with MongoDB. It looks correct to me. Possibly your collection data does not match the class definitions

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted answer did not work for me. It returned nothing. You can use the following code:

`var activeDriver = await _carCollection.AsQueryable().Where(a => a.Id == carId).SelectMany(a => a.Drivers).Where(e => e.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();`

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487401/c-sharp-mongodb-find-item-in-array-and-select-only-this-item)