# C# Mongodb. Find item in array and select only this item

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have User object:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("599e670f2720317af451db9e"),
    "Cars" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Car 1",
            "Labels" : [
                {
                    "Label" : "Main", 
                    "Color" : "#F49973"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Name" : "Car 2",               
            "Labels" : [    
                {
                    "Label" : "Main", 
                    "Color" : "#F49973"
                },
                {
                    "Label" : "Secondary", 
                    "Color" : "#E2E2E2"
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find document by user id and car name, then select this car. I am trying to do this:

```
 await _collection.AsQueryable().Where(u => u.Id == someId && u.Cars.Any(s => s.Name == someName))
                .Select(u => u.Cars[-1])
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

In result, I want to get single `Car` object, but, I get `null`. How to properly to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        var collection = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Rootobject>("test");

        ObjectId someId = new ObjectId("599e670f2720317af451db9e");
        string someName = "Car 1";

        var item = await collection.AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => x.Id == someId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Cars)
            .Where(x => x.Name == someName)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This generates the below aggregation query:

```
{aggregate([{ "$match" : { "_id" : ObjectId("599e670f2720317af451db9e") } }, { "$unwind" : "$Cars" }, { "$project" : { "Cars" : "$Cars", "_id" : 0 } }, { "$match" : { "Cars.Name" : "Car 1" } }])}
```

which spits out the following results:

```
{ "Cars" : { "Name" : "Car 1", "Labels" : [ { "Label" : "Main", "Color" : "#F49973" } ] } }
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I tried almost the same query, but `x.Name == someName` I had in the first Where like: `x.Cars.Any( c.Name == someName)` and it didn't work properly.

Comment: I find that using Linq with MongoDB can sometimes complicate things, might be worth having a look at the query builder within mongo. :-)

Comment: Actually, 90% of my queries are written with help of `Builders` class, but I think LINQ query is more consice.